# Proving convergence of a ratio of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've only just started looking at sequences and their limits:

If $x_n \to a$ and $y_n \to b \neq 0$ then prove $z_n = \frac{x_n}{y_n}$ tends to the limit $(\frac{a}{b})$.

I know the definition of the limit, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n = a + \alpha_n$, $y_n = b + \beta_n$, where $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ are indefinitely small.

Then $$\gamma_n=\frac{x_n}{y_n}-\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a + \alpha_n}{b + \beta_n}-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{(a + \alpha_n)b - (b + \beta_n)a}{y_nb} = \frac{\alpha_nb -\beta_na}{b}\frac{1}{y_n}$$

where $1 / y_n$ is limited (easy to proof) and $(\alpha_nb -\beta_na) /b $ is indefinitely small. Hence $\gamma_n$ is indefinitely small. That's all.